# Traverse multiple cells not in a range stored in a name using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a name that contains this, for example:
=(B1;C3;E4)

It is stored with the name, "Cells1".

I want to take those cells using VBA and work with them, and change their cell value. I have the following code:

```vb
Sub Vaciar_nombres()
    Dim R1 As 

    REM Following line throws a 1004 error.
    Set R1 = test_sheet.Names("Cells1").RefersToRange

    Debug.Print (VarType(R1))
End Sub
```

I tried using a Range type variable. It throws a 1004 error.

Also, I don't know if I have to write those cells in that name like:
=(B1;C4;C5)
OR
=B2;C4;C5

Don't take into account the semicolon notation, in my language, it is written like that when I create a name and select different cells using the Ctrl key.

Comment: Loop through the [`Areas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.areas)? You can't read the value of a multi-area range into an array, though it's not clear whether you want to work with an array, or simply to loop through each cell.

Comment: @BigBen Excatly that, I want to loop though each cell.

Comment: Then you need a loop: `For Each cell in hoja_de_pruebas.Names("Celdas1").RefersToRange`?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

  Dim i As Integer
  Dim x As Range
  i = 1

  For Each x In Range("Cells1")
     x.Value = i
     i = i + 2
  Next x
  
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thats ok, the problem is not that i don't know how to loop, but I don't know how exactly to get those cells from that name and store it in a variable, and which variable type it should be, so that I can loope through it later.

Comment: @Lorthas - it should be a `Range` and you should use `RefersToRange`. Make sure to use `Set` as well.

Comment: @BigBen I edited te question a bit. I tried using ranges but i get a 1004 error.

Comment: @BigBen I created a new name from the interface, and in the formula field after writing the name, I clicked every cell I wanted to add to that name using the Ctrl key so it added the ; automatically. I thought then I could get all those cells using VBA.

Comment: @Lorthas, I'm at a loss as to why you want to put them in a variable for looping later when you can just use the Range Name to do the same as above? Maybe clarification as to why you want to store them in a variable would help lead to a better solution.

Comment: @RetiredGeek I thought that was the way to do it, because even if I add columns or rows, the stored cells in that name stay being the same. If I hardcode the range references, when adding rows or columns would not work as I intend since the cell reference wouldn't be dynamic in that way.
I thought that a Range name was just creating a name and selecting cells. I wanted to create them inside the names interface rather than u sing VBA.

Comment: @Lorthas,  If you add a row, say between D4 & D5 the Named range will now contain B1,D4,D6. Is this what you wish or not? If you want the reference to D5 to remain D5 then yes you need to find a way to store the initial values of the Range Name in a variable.